# LiveData Observer inside another LiveData Observer

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I'm working in some search option in my app. And it includes two connected tables in database. I'm new in room and I need something like this:

```
viewModel.getAllImages().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), images -> {
    for (Image i : images) {
        viewModel.getAllMetadata(i.getId()).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), list -> {
            for(Metadata m: list){
                for (Metadata em : listMetadata) {
                    if (em.getId() == m.get() && em.getValue().equals(m.getValue())) {
                        imageList.add(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**listMetadata** is collected from user inputs. **imageList** is where result are stored.

This is called when button is clicked. And it's working only after second time i click it, but it gives me double results. First time it just says that imageList is empty. Second time, sometimes it's double populated, and sometimes only once, but it works only on second click.

I don't know if this is the right way of using LiveData, and I would really appreciate same help how to do this.

Thanks in advance.